# why array manual and array that maked from database give different result with strpos processing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, strpos

i have code like this..

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbmobile");
$arr=array();
$array_category=array("JAS HU","PAYUNG","SANDAL","SARUNG","SEPATU","TALI J","TIKAR"," ");
$array_produk=array();
$sql="select cgrpdesc from tm_tampung";
$hasil=mysql_query($sql);

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
        array_push($array_produk,$data[0]);
}

for($i=0;$i<count($array_produk);$i++){
    if($e>0){
         $e=0;
     }
     for($a=0;$a<count($array_category);$a++){

            $fa=strpos($array_produk[$i],$array_category[$a]);
            if($fa!==FALSE && $e==0){
                array_push($arr,$array_category[$a]);
                $e++;
            }
    }
}

for($i=0;$i<count($array_produk);$i++){
        if($arr[$i]==" "){
            $arr[$i]="NULL";
        }

        echo $i.".".$array_produk[$i]."=".$arr[$i];
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

it works perfectly and here is the example result

0.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =SANDAL
1.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SANDAL 
2.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SANDAL
3.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SEPATU
4.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SEPATU
5.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =SEPATU
6.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SEPATU
7.SANDAL PCU KECIL 30-33 =SANDAL
8.SANDAL PCU KECIL 30-33 =SANDAL
9.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =SANDAL
10.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =SANDAL
11.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =SANDAL
12.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SANDAL
13.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SANDAL
14.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =SANDAL
15.SANDAL PCU MINI 24-26 =SANDAL
16.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =SANDAL
17.SANDAL PCU TANGGUNG 34-37 =SANDAL
18.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =SANDA
L
19.SANDAL PCU BABY 18-23 =SANDAL

but the problem occured when i delete manual **array_category()** in my code to array_category from database... beacause i wanted a dynamic array of string that will be checked with strpos function ...

here is the code after  i change to dynamic array..

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbmobile");
$arr=array();
//$array_category=array("JAS HU","PAYUNG","SANDAL","SARUNG","SEPATU","TALI J","TIKAR"," ");
$sql1="select kategori from tm_kategori";
$hasil1=mysql_query($sql1);
$array_category=array();
$array_produk=array();
$sql="select cgrpdesc from tm_tampung";
$hasil=mysql_query($sql);

while($data1=mysql_fetch_array($hasil1)){
        array_push($array_category,$data1[0]);
}

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
        array_push($array_produk,$data[0]);
}

for($i=0;$i<count($array_produk);$i++){
    if($e>0){
         $e=0;
     }
     for($a=0;$a<count($array_category);$a++){

            $fa=strpos($array_produk[$i],$array_category[$a]);
            if($fa!==FALSE && $e==0){
                array_push($arr,$array_category[$a]);
                $e++;
            }
    }
}
for($i=0;$i<count($array_produk);$i++){
        if($arr[$i]==" "){
            $arr[$i]="NULL";
        }

        echo $i.".".$array_produk[$i]."=".$arr[$i];
        echo "<br>";
    }


?>
```

and the result is

0.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
1.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
2.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
3.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
4.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
5.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
6.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
7.SANDAL PCU KECIL 30-33 =NULL
8.SANDAL PCU KECIL 30-33 =NULL
9.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
10.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
11.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
12.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
13.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
14.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =NULL
15.SANDAL PCU MINI 24-26 =NULL
16.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
17.SANDAL PCU TANGGUNG 34-37 =NULL
18.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
19.SANDAL PCU BABY 18-23 =NULL
20.SANDAL PCU BABY 18-23 =NULL
21.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
22.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL
23.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =NULL

can anyone give me a support to fix the code or explain why this error happen? is strpos function bug?

thank you :)
any help will be apreciated

Comment: Please post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: thankyou, i just try to explain with detail explanation

Comment: check the result of var_dump($array_category);

Comment: thanks .. i know the error and i fix it... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$data[0]` in

```
while($data1=mysql_fetch_array($hasil1)){
        array_push($array_category,$data[0]);
}
```

to `$data1[0]`

```
while($data1=mysql_fetch_array($hasil1)){
        array_push($array_category,$data1[0]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply i have change the code like you say,... but the result is still blank

Comment: here is the result 

0.SANDAL PCU DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =<br>
1.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =<br>
2.SANDAL PCU DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =<br>
3.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =<br>
4.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =<br>
5.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA WANITA 36-40 =<br>
6.SEPATU INJECTION DEWASA PRIA 38-44 =<br>
7.SANDAL PCU KECIL 30-33 =<br>